# Why should constructors on abstract classes be protected, not public?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, access-modifiers

ReSharper suggests changing the accessibility of a `public` constructor in an `abstract` class to `protected`, but it does not state the rationale behind this.

Can you shed some light?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Simply because being public makes no sense in an abstract class.  An abstract class by definition cannot be instantiated directly.  It can only be instantiated by an instance of a derived type. Therefore the only types that should have access to a constructor are its derived types and hence protected makes much more sense than public.  It more accurately describes the accessibility.

Comment: In other words: why would you want to pollute other people's IntelliSense with useless garbage?

Comment: @Andre constructors only show in intellisense for new and base calls. Typically abstract classes are filtered out of new before accessibility is considered because checking for abstract is very easy and cheap.

Comment: So given this, shouldn't the compiler enforce that abstract classes **can't** have `public` constructors?

Comment: I came here because I was looking for answer what should I do if abstract classes never existed. I was thinking if giving a constructor a protected access would be a solution. So maybe it was like that in the past before abstract classes were invented? And that's why programmers should use protected constructors in abstract classes, because it's a tradition? I'm not old programmer, I'm just wondering how it was. Newest Visual Studio doesn't show any warning, so I think it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: I didn't see this question was so old. In those days this problem is described in MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182126.aspx). Andrew Troelsen and Philip Japikse in their book "C# 6.0 and the .NET 4.6 Framework" (which I think is very good) make public constructors in their examples showing abstract classes and don't mention about protected ones.

Comment: @JaredPar: "Typically abstract classes are filtered out of new" - which usually causes an annoying lack of IntelliSense when declaring an array of an abstract class.

Comment: Well said. I have no idea why this is not emphasized in every OOP PHP book.

Comment: @alcoholisevil class has to be declared abstract so that you can have abstract members; protected constructors don't communicate to the compiled the same intent

Answer (score 26):

It technically makes no difference whatsoever if you make the constructor `public` instead of `protected` on an abstract class. The accessibility/visibility of the constructor is still exactly the same: the same class or derived classes. The two keywords have indistinguishable effects for all intents and purposes.

So, this choice is only a matter of style: type `protected` to satisfy the Object Oriented savvy people.

---

Reflection will by default only include the constructor when it is `public`, but you cannot call that constructor anyway.

IntelliSense will show the `public` constructor when typing `new`, but you cannot call that constructor anyway.

The assembly's metadata will reflect the fact that the constructor is public or protected.

Comment: Except that stating the visibility as `public` is not truthful.

Comment: His answer gives the functional differences between the two which is exactly what I was looking for.  Whether it's truthful doesn't matter, and besides that's an issue for the c# language to tackle, not developers.

Answer (score -3):

It is good OO practice.

```
public abstract class ExampleAbstractClass
{
    protected ExampleAbstractClass()
    {
      // :::
    }
}
```

You only want the inheriting child classes to have access to the constructor.  The only way to do that is by making the constructor protected.
Keep in mind, when you add parameters to these constructors, it is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: What makes it different when you add parameters?  The constructor will still only be called by derived classes.

Comment: It will force all the inheritor constructors to have the parameter in their signature, whether needed or not.

Comment: @SrikarDoddi: No, it does not. The inherited constructors just need to call `: base(...)` and pass something, but that something can also be constants or values retrieved from elsewhere.