# Can an abstract class contain a public method?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Constructors of an `abstract`  `class` shouldn't be `public` and they should be `protected`. My question is about methods in that `abstract`  `class`. Can we declare them as `public` or they should be `protected` too for the same reason?

Comment: I would revisit and think about your assumption about the constructor before you move to the methods.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761854

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well, I would disagree with Resharper, whether or not a class is directly instantiable should not drive the accessibility modifier on the constructor. If I change my mind about the abstract nature of the class, now I have two things to change instead of one.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Fair enough, but I suspect that, if a class was originally designed to be abstract, you'd have to change more than just the access modifiers anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, also a fair point.

Comment: guys! Protected constructors in Abstract classes is Not my question and it is TRUE. It is said both on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229047.aspx and also in Framework Design Guidelines book. Thanks.

Comment: @BDotA: The access modifier distinction for constructor methods in abstract classes (guidelines notwithstanding) is not especially meaningful; the behavior is the same in either case. That is *not* true of the abstract class's methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The justification for constructors on `abstract` types being `protected` is that there is simply no other entity that could call the constructor other than a derived type.  Making the constructor `public` is meaningless in this case as it can't ever be invoked outside the type hierarchy.  Hence the recommendation is to use `protected` as it's the most appropriate access modifier.

The same logic doesn't hold true with other members on the type. They can be freely invoked from outside the type hierarchy should their access modifier permit it.

```
public abstract class Dog {

  // Public is appropriate here as any consumer of Dog could access
  // Breed on an instantiated object
  public abstract string Breed { get; }

  // Public would be meaningless here. It's not legal to say 
  // 'new Dog' because 'Dog' is abstract. You can only say 
  // 'new Poodle' or 'new Bulldog'.  Only derived types like
  // Poodle or Bulldog could invoke the Dog constructor hence it's
  // protected
  protected Dog() { }
}

public class Poodle : Dog { } 
public class Bulldog : Dog { }
```

Whether or not a particular member should be `public` or `protected` is highly dependent upon the particular API.  The reasoning should be the exact same for `abstract` types as it is for non-abstract types

Answer (score 6):

Abstract classes shouldn't have public constructors because they don't make sense.  Abstract classes are incomplete, so allowing a public constructor (which anyone could call) wouldn't work as you can't instantiate an instance anyway.

Methods on abstract classes are another story.  You can have implementation in an abstract class, which is the behavior that all subclasses will inherit.  Think of a Shape class.  Its purpose is to draw a shape on the screen, so it makes sense to make a Draw method public as you'll want callers to be able to ask your Shape to draw.  The method itself can be abstract, forcing subclasses to implement, or possibly provide an implementation which may or may not allow overriding.  It depends on what the defined behavior of your class should be.

Comment: An abstract class _can_ have a public ctor. They're just not very useful.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  Ah, I thought that generated a compiler error.  I'll update, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your use case.  If you want the methods of the abstract class visible to instances of your derived class, you should make them public.  If, on the other hand, you want the methods visible only to your derived class, you should make them protected.